# live view of bottom navigation in design view is not showing icons and the menu resource

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]The bottom navigation view is not showing the icons in it, in the live-  design view of the android studio as of `material io 1.5.0.` and I see on my previous projects that in `material io 1.3.0` it's working on old but not in the new version.

I am just seeing an empty bottom navigation bar, and nothing on it. I will really appreciate your help in this regard.

here is the code XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_semirec_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_semirec_top"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:itemIconSize="20dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation project (':resource')

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0'

}
```

Comment: did you check in physical device because some times  it happens.. but work on mobile perfectly..

Comment: yes, it works on physical but I need it in design view. for that I need any solution tnx

Comment: then you need to change your phone screen size . in your design you will see bar where you can select pixel xL. so you are using constraint layout for that you have used so many margins ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurred while using the new material io 1.5.0 library, and it's working fine on 1.3.0.

Thanks Niaj Mahmud for your help and support

Answer (score 1):

remove
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:itemIconSize="20dp"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Comment: when i add this line mine was also as like you

Comment: I removed that! and also updated the image in the question see what happened is now nothing shows on . the color is also gone now.

Comment: did you change anything in color.xml or themes.xml ???

Comment: I have  one resource module that all other modules depends on that and yes I customise just colors of that module

Comment: I am sure I rechecked no problem is there  just  the  problem is with material  io version 1.5.0. because with 1.3.0 its working

Comment: your code with result 
   https://imgur.com/a/3vScMNg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242610/discussion-between-mohammad-khalid-shehab-and-niaj-mahmud).

Answer (score 0):

Update material library to latest version (now 1.6.1) solve your problem :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

**Note:** You can find the latest version in this link :

https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material