# Unable to see any icons at the Bottom Navigation bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to display the icon images on my bottom navigation bar. No matter what I try I still can't get it. I have been trying so many different ways to solve but to no avail. Could someone please help me on this? Maybe I have missed out on something.

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout">
    </FrameLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>```
````

````
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_donate"
    android:icon="@drawable/donate_icon"
    android:title="Donate"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_status"
    android:icon="@drawable/status_icon"
    android:title="Status"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_history"
    android:icon="@drawable/history_icon"
    android:title="History"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/logout_icon"
    android:title="Log Out"/>
    </menu>
    ```
````

The image link below is how the display is as of now.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH6AQ.png

Comment: yes in physical device it's work properly but in preview it does not show. this issue is for material version 1.5.0  .. try material 1.3.0  version  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356663/live-view-of-bottom-navigation-in-design-view-is-not-showing-icons-and-the-menu/71356797#71356797

Comment: oh yes. It was due to the material version. Now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your layout height is set to 0dp
 `android:layout_height="0dp"` where it is matching the constraints it is given. I have not seen your display but I'm guessing the frame layout is hiding your bottomNavView.
Change it to

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavView">
    </FrameLayout>

 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```

**EDIT**
With help from @Niaj Mahmud .

Change the material version in your app level build.gradle files from 1.5.0 to 1.3.0

Comment: I have tried using the code you have provided. It still dosent work. Is there a way I should show you my result?

Comment: Yeah attach what you're getting as an image and also add all the whole code

Comment: Yup attached. The constraint is locked to the top I think

Comment: check this once

Comment: hmm no difference https://imgur.com/a/p5hs0nZ

Comment: It wont show on the layoutpreview.. Did you run it on an actual device and check. also for now can you change it to a Constraint Layout instead of a coordinator layotu

Comment: Hi Narendra, after changing my material version from with help from @Niaj Mahmud from 1.5.0 to 1.3.0 it worked perfectly. Thanks for helping !

Comment: cool . .. I'll just ad it as an edit ..so that it helps others

Answer (score 0):

yes in physical device it's work properly but in preview it does not show. this issue is for material version 1.5.0 .. try material 1.3.0 version
[live view of bottom navigation in design view is not showing icons and the menu resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356663/live-view-of-bottom-navigation-in-design-view-is-not-showing-icons-and-the-menu/71356797#71356797)